# VBA decimal > 1.0 to time hh:mm:ss format

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I'm doing several calculations in a worksheet starting from a cell with format and value like this:

A1 = 00:30:00

In another cell I divide those 25 minutes by 3 in a formula:

A2 = A1/3 = 10:45:00

When executing a vba module like this:

```
t_weld = Sheets("TIME").Range("A2").Value
```

The value of "t_weld" variable is "0.447916". After adding and multiplying this variable with another ones, the final value is greater than "1.0". The result in hh:mm:ss format do not return values more than 24 hours, so when the value in decimals is >1.0 (more than 24 hours) it starts again from 00:00:00.

What I need is to format that value in order to show results like this 48:35:00.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exceed 24 hrs with this:

```
Sub dural()
   x = 1.23456789
   With ActiveCell
      .Value = x
      .NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm:ss"
   End With
End Sub
```

as shown in both the Formula Bar and the cell:

[image]